# how to move canvas content without rerender

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, svelte

I am basically writing a mindmap app where I want to be able to click and drag the map to move it around.

So I've started using HTML canvas for this and I draw directly to it, but it seems super slow.
Especially when dragging as it needs to rerender the entire canvas.

So my question is: is there any way of keeping the content and just basically translating the content without having to clear everything and render each part individually slightly to the left?

I tried "just" using `canvas.getContext("2d").translate(camera.x, camera.y)` on mousedrag but it doesn't really do anything.

I am using svelte as a framework

Comment: Save the canvas as an image, then just render the image

Comment: @ASDFGerte There is no need to save the canvas as an Image (which can be very slow on some devices).The canvas is image (like) and can be drawn via the 2D API on another canvas, or even back on its self, using `ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)`

Comment: @Blindman67 yes, that's true. My comment doesn't give a full answer, it just hints towards one possible path for a solution. If the canvas itself is used as storage, then it has to be a different canvas, than the one used for actually drawing the translated view the user will see. Some additional logic is necessary anyways, one way or the other.